# How can I group data with the same name in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a DataFrame with three columns:'region', 'year', 'grdp'.

How do I group data with the same name in 'region' column.

Here's the code to create a sample dataset:

[image]

Here's the desired result: store data of values with the same name in the 'region' column

ex) 'region' column has three "서울특별시" data. I want to group the three "서울특별시" data in three columns and assign it to a variable

[image]

Comment: Do not take screenshot of code. Rather, copy and paste the code in your question. No one is going to type this out to do you a favour.

Comment: I've seen this exact question before. I believe there was a useful answer then... 

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "grouping in 3 columns"?

If you mean you want N data frames, each populated with the rows that have the same value for column A, then `split(df, df$A)` does what you want.

```
x <- c(2, 2, 3)
y <- c(2, 2, 3)
z <- c(2, 4, 5)

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

dfs <- split(df, df$x)
```

Note that grouping along x will put the first 2 rows in one frame, and the last in another.

```
dfs$'2'
>   x y z
> 1 2 2 2
> 2 2 2 4
```